# what's meaning of %@ ... @ in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In [themes.rb](https://github.com/ricodigo/shapado/blob/master/lib/jobs/themes.rb#L52), there is the following code included in the `%@ @`:

```
 %@
 $has_bg_image: #{theme.has_bg_image?};
 $bg_color: ##{theme.bg_color};
 $fg_color: ##{theme.fg_color};
 $bg_image_url: '/_files/themes/bg_image/#{theme.group_id}/#     {theme.id}/#{theme.version}.png';
 $topbar_color: ##{theme.topbar_color};
 $logo_url: '/_files/groups/logo/#{theme.group_id}/#  {theme.version}.png';
 $view_bg_color: ##{theme.view_bg_color};
 $brand_color: ##{theme.brand_color};
 $fluid: #{theme.fluid};
 $bg_shadow:      #999;
 @
```

what reference about the syntax can I find? It is awkward that I don't know how to search the special characters like `%@` in `google` and `SO`!

Comment: another way to write it, would be to use `%( .................................. )`

Comment: By the way if you were curious it looks as though the function this is used in is just building and returning a string of LESS or some other similar CSS thing with variables.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That syntax will create a string using interpolation with all of the text between the two '@' characters. You can use any delimiter after the '%' that you would like, as long as it doesn't conflict with characters in your text. Here is a reference for it: http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#strings

Comment: very clean, concise and accurate answer. nice job

Comment: This syntax basically just creates string literals. Starting with a percent and then you wrap whatever you want in a string with matching non alpha-numeric characters.

Comment: "Percent strings" are also documented at [ruby-doc.org](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html) in the very last paragraph. It almost looks like an afterthought. *"If you are using “(”, “[”, “{”, “<” you must close it with “)”, “]”, “}”, “>” respectively. You may use most other non-alphanumeric characters for percent string delimiters such as “%”, “|”, “^”, etc."*

Comment: @DickieBoy: My gut says "No", but not for great reasons. If I were working on the Ruby language, and I'd implemented a subset of percent strings as an alternative syntax for heredocs, I'd have documented that. But the documentation for heredocs is quite different from the documentation for the similar subset of percent strings.